# Cleaning up a comparison

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I have a simple set of array comparisons and was just wondering if there was a neater way of writing it. Basically its

`e[i][2] === e[k][2] && e[i][3] === e[k][3]`

Is there a way of compressing this down or is that just the way it is

Thanks in advance

Comment: Whats inside the array?

Comment: Contents from a google sheets. I'm actually using GAS

Answer (score 1):

If you like, you could take a function for comparing, which takes `e[i]` and `e[k]` as parameter.

```
const compare = (a, b) => a[2] === b[2] && a[3] === b[3]

// usage
compare(e[i], e[k])
```

Comment: Thanks Nina. That's probably not gaining me too much as it in a for statement but good to know.

Comment: Note that Google Apps Script does not support arrow functions

Answer (score 1):

You could use some curried functions to beautify this:

```
  const compare = (...keys) => (a, b) => keys.every(k => a[k] === b[k]);
```

So you can do:

```
 compare(2, 3)(e[i], e[k]);
```

Comment: Thanks Jonas. Think I'll stick with what I've got. Its messy but less typing :-)

Comment: Note that Google Apps Script has no support for spread or arrow functions